# How to change the type of e.target.value of a select onchange event from string type to union type of strings?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have a union type of strings

```
type UnionOfStrings = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
const Arr : UnionOfStrings[] = ['a','b','c']
const update = (val: UnionOfStrings ) => {
  do some stuff
}
```

I have a select element

```
<select
  onChange={e => update({ value: e.target.value})}
>
  {Arr.map(val => <option value={val}>{val}</option>)}
</select>
```

because the type of e.target.value is string, I have to change the update function to

```
const update = (val: UnionOfStrings | string) => {
  do some stuff
}
```

which makes the type UnionOfStrings nonsense.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)? They can be handy in this sort of situation.

Comment: I'm not sure about how I can solve it with type assertion. Could you please make it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

When you know type information that TypeScript doesn't — especially at the "boundaries" of your TypeScript code like this, where you're interacting with a browser API that doesn't know anything about TypeScript — one option is to simply tell TypeScript the correct type, using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). So if TypeScript knows only that `e.target.value` is a `string`, but you know that it's more specifically a `UnionOfStrings`, then you can write `e.target.value as UnionOfStrings` to make TypeScript know what you know.

That said, type assertions are a bit scary — by design, TypeScript can't check that the assertion is correct, so you have to be quite confident that you're getting it right — so some hesitation is warranted.

One alternative, since you have only a small number of possible values, would be to write a small helper function that converts from `string` to `UnionOfStrings` by actually finding the correct `UnionOfStrings`:

```
function toUnionOfStrings(s : string) : UnionOfStrings {
  for (const val of Arr) {
    if (val === s) {
      return val;
    }
  }
  throw new Error("Invalid UnionOfStrings: " + s)
}
```

The above is more expensive — instead of a type assertion that gets discarded at compile-time, it's an actual function that loops over all the possible values until it finds the right one — but it actually validates the correctness. You may (or may not) find that to be worth the cost.